# How to stop sound when the game restarts in LUA

Tags: lua

Sounds of the game
[image: 1]

code where i try to implement the sound
[image: 2]

So I am trying to implement a sound at the end of the game, the sound has a duration of 30 seconds, however when I try to continue and make a new game. The sound keeps on playing until the full 30 seconds is up. I don't want that, I would like it when the sound stops when the game restarts. I decided to do a if else statement and other methods by none of them worked. I looked online but not helpful. If anyone has any ideas, it would be helpful. The following links are my code.

Comment: It is preferred that you post code as text in your question, not screen shots. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask the section `Help others reproduce the problem` covers how you should avoid use of images of code and errors

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation there are two ways to stop a source.

`Souce:stop()`

and

`love.audio.stop()` or `love.audio.stop(sourceList)`

Your logic is weird. Unfortunately I cannot copy your code to quote it. The ``` stop() in `` if gamestate == 'done' then ``` is unreachable.